# Why is my first post in my loop indented unexpectedly

Tags: html

When I display my posts using loops. My first post in my loop did gets indented unexpectedly. Below I will provide code and image of the indent.

code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}


<br/>
<div class="container">   
<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
<br/>
{% for post in object_list %}
    {% if forloop.counter <= 15 %}

       
    <li><a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk %}"> {{post.title}}</a>
         -  {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }} <br/> {{post.body}}</li>
    <br/>
<style>
    a {
        text-transform: capitalize;
    }
</style>
</ul>

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>

{% endblock %}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you provide your html file?

Comment: can you add the data of post body for all <li> ?

Comment: Looks like you close your <ul>  inside your loop. the ul should close outside the loop. Once you fix this all the li items will be indented, and then you can fix using css for the ul li

Comment: I don't think `<style><\style>` should be inside loop either.

Comment: @RobMoll Agreed, should be outside the loop otherwise you are just repeating the same style

Comment: Note: the `<br>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Oh Ok I saw a youtuber using it in html so I thought that was right. Btw what do I have to use to make space in between two stuff other than spaces. @Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've notice there your `<ul>` tag is put outside of the loop. But your `</ul>` is put inside of the loop.

You should move your `</ul>` outside of the loop

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTx41.png)